# Spring MVC equivalent of Action Mapping in Struts 2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, action-mapping

Is there an equivalient/similar action mapping xml configuration available for SpringMVC just as there is for Struts 2?

e.g. in a Struts2 app I have this:

```xml
<action name="index" class="homeAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="myAppVarsBasic" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp16/home.jsp</result>
    <result name="userDisplay">/WEB-INF/jsp16/userDisplay.jsp</result>
    <result name="changePassword" type="redirectAction" >passwordReset!changePass.do</result>
</action>
```

Is there a similar way to configure action mappings, redirects and to where with Spring MVC using xml config?

I'm teaching myself (with help of SO and Google) S2 to SpringMVC but find most resources *seem* to handle redirect directly from the action (or is that Controller in MVC?) e.g.:

```
return "redirect:index";
```

Comment: Only question why? Do the framework that you know better.

Comment: Can't get a job anymore with S2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equivalient/similar action mapping xml configuration available for SpringMVC just as there is for Struts 2?

Spring MVC has xml based configuration, annotations, and JavaConfig. It has several namespaces in their xml config files. The most usable is `beans` namespace. There you can define your beans configuration. You can define a path in the bean's `name` attribute or use `@RequestMapping` annotation.

When Struts2 is integrated with Spring you can configure actions in `struts.xml` and define beans for action classes in the `applicationContext.xml`. Instead of `class` in the action config you just place a bean's id.

In Spring MVC you can map request path to a method with `@RequestMapping` annotation. It's similar like Struts1 mapped their actions. In the Spring MVC 4 It has also support for wildcards and regex to match the request path.

Spring has also interceptors but they are just pointcuts in the AOP namespace. Of course you can use them in Spring config.

Results in Struts2 are just another actions that executes when the initial action ends. Spring MVC returns a `View` object with the `Model`. It can return a string, or another object, or nothing. The result in Spring MVC is what actually requested method returns. The result is handled by the view resolver. Spring MVC has many view resolves that you can configure as beans that are capable to handle a servlet dispatcher's request.

---

> Is there a similar way to configure action mappings, redirects and to where with Spring MVC using xml config?

One of them is `XmlViewResolver` that is similar to the Struts 2 action config. You can read more abour these beans on the [Spring](http://spring.io/) site. Using this resolver you define views via `views.xml` that you feed to this resolver as property and use the view names mapped to each JSP.

---

Comment: Thank you Roman.  With this answer I am now armed with the right place and terminology to take the next step,  Very much appreciated! KA.